# What do these terms actually mean about linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In a book it is written  " *Let A be a fixed $m\times n $ matrix with entries in the field $\mathbb F$. The function $T$ defined by $ T(X)=AX$ is a linear  transformation from $\mathbb F^{n\times 1 }$ into $\mathbb F^{m\times 1 }$.  The function $U$ defined by $U(\alpha)=\alpha A$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb F^m$ into $\mathbb F^n$.*"

Here how the transform takes place from $\mathbb F^{n\times 1 }$ into $\mathbb F^{m\times 1 }$? Please explain with an example.

Comment: if u multiply n dimensional vector with mxn matrix then you get m dimensional vector . So i guess you are talking about this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
d & e \\
g & h  \end{array} when multiplied with 
\begin{array}{ccc}
1   \\
2 \\  \end{array} 
gives
\begin{array}{ccc}
a +2 b  \\
d +2e \\
g +2 h  \end{array}
which is three dimensional vector

Here i have adopted the common notion of visualising linear transformation as a matrix.

Comment: @mahavir space of 3 dimensions to space of 2 dimensions

Comment: @mahavir edited my comment see here we are transforming a three dimensional space to a two dimensional . And the vectors so created in 2d space scale if you scale vectors in 3d space and they get added in 2d space if you add them in 3d space.